# Why fitting curve in ggplot2 does not smooth?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a 4-parameters fitting curve, but the line is not smooth. Could you please help me?
[image: My result here]

My data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14cnuGEu7YByGTWIdth5ijbsxdNMZ5WxU/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113011478413339776238&rtpof=true&sd=true

Thank you very much!

```r
#AutoGrowthCurve
#Set working dir
getwd()
setwd("")
#Call library
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
library("ggsci")
library("ggplot2")
library("gridExtra")
library(drc) #for fitting curves with 4 parameters

#input data
df <- readxl::read_excel("data.xlsx", range = "Q1:AC13", 
                   col_names = T)
df <- df[,-12]

df <- melt(df, id.vars = c("Strains"), value.name = "Growth", variable.name = "Concentrations")

df$Strains <- as.factor(df$Strains)
df$Concentrations <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Concentrations))
df$Strains <- factor(df$Strains, levels = c("P", "T", "N"))


#to modify the x axis
lab_x <- c("0", "0.4",  "0.8",  "2.6",  "3.1",  "6.3",  "12.5", "25",   "50",   "100",  "200") # add concentrations we need to plot
brk_x <- c(0.1, 0.4,    0.8,    1.6,    3.1,    6.3,    12.5,   25, 50, 100,    200) #add concentrations we will use to calculate


svg("mic_cau1.svg",              # File name
    width = 5.5, height = 4)  # Paper size


# Creating a plot
ggplot(data = df,
       aes(Concentrations, Growth, col = Strains, shape = Strains)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = drm, method.args = list(fct = L.4()), se = F, size = 1) +
  geom_point(size = 4, alpha = 0.8)+ 
  theme_classic() + coord_trans(x="log2") + 
  scale_color_manual(name = "Strains", values=c("#000000", "#099963", "#804003")) + 
  scale_shape_manual(name = "Strains", values = c(17, 15, 19))+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 16), axis.text = element_text(size = 16), 
        axis.line =element_line(size=1),
        legend.position = c(0.8, 0.6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = lab_x, breaks = brk_x) + xlab("Concentration (µg/ml)") + ylab("Growth (%)")


# Closing the graphical device
dev.off()
```

Comment: Perhaps increase the number of points the line is evaluated at by adding `n = 1000` to `geom_smooth`?

Comment: It may also be that you have a non standard x-axis scale and so the drawing looks strange. It might look better in a purely log transformed scale for example